# Android error when uploading image from gallery to server

Tags: php, android, file-upload

I am getting a error when i try to uploade an image from my application to my server. i can start my application and choose an image but the image will not uploade to my server.

Here is my android code:

```
package com.example.testuploade4;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int SELECT_IMAGE = 1;
    String selectedPath;

    String urlString = "http://jadder.dk/sjov/uploade1.php";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        openGallery();
    }

    public void openGallery() {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image "),
                SELECT_IMAGE);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE) {
                System.out.println("SELECT_IMAGE");
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("SELECT_IMAGE Path : " + selectedPath);
                doFileUpload();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    private void doFileUpload() {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                DataOutputStream dos = null;
                DataInputStream inStream = null;
                String lineEnd = "rn";
                String twoHyphens = "--";
                String boundary = "*****";
                int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
                byte[] buffer;
                int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
                String responseFromServer = "";
                try {
                    // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                            new File(selectedPath));
                    // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    // Allow Inputs
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    // Don't use a cached copy.
                    conn.setUseCaches(false);
                    // Use a post method.
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                            "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";name=\""
                            + selectedPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    // create a buffer of maximum size
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                    // read file and write it into form...
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    while (bytesRead > 0) {
                        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    }
                    // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                    // close streams
                    Log.e("Debug", "File is written");
                    fileInputStream.close();
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();
                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
                }
                // ------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
                try {
                    inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                    String str;

                    while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                        Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);
                    }
                    inStream.close();

                } catch (IOException ioex) {
                    Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
                }

                return null;
            }
        }.execute();

    }
}
```

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
// Where the file is going to be placed
$target_path = "uploads/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
    echo "target_path: " .$target_path;
}
?>
```

Here is the error:

```
11-15 14:07:07.383: I/System.out(28801): SELECT_IMAGE
11-15 14:07:07.393: I/System.out(28801): SELECT_IMAGE Path : /storage/emulated/0/Download/560843_531646073574745_683776063_n.jpg
11-15 14:07:07.583: D/dalvikvm(28801): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 103K, 2% free 9574K/9744K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
11-15 14:07:07.603: E/Debug(28801): File is written
11-15 14:07:08.284: E/Debug(28801): Server Response There was an error uploading the file, please try again!filename: target_path: uploads/
```

Comment: try $target_path = getcwd() ."uploads/"; on your php script

Comment: When i try to do that i get a different error message. the error message:                                                            11-15 15:01:40.684: E/Debug(32262): File is written
11-15 15:01:41.374: E/Debug(32262): Server Response There was an error uploading the file, please try again!filename: target_path: /var/www/vhosts/jadder.dk/httpdocs/sjovuploads/

Comment: Ok then, try try $target_path = getcwd() ."/uploads/"; (it was a missed / xD) ...and check that the folder /var/www/vhosts/jadder.dk/httpdocs/sjov/uploads/ exist and have the right perms

Comment: I tried do that but still the same error. The folders are right and i the perms to. I get the error still                          11-15 15:18:21.622: E/Debug(1308): File is written
11-15 15:18:22.132: E/Debug(1308): Server Response There was an error uploading the file, please try again!filename: target_path: /var/www/vhosts/jadder.dk/httpdocs/sjov/uploads/

Comment: The file that you are uploading...try it with a file with a size lesser than 100 kb pls, just for check xD

Comment: Check this answer...he have working upload code in android with a php script, just like you...maybe that can gives yous some hints http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339294/equalhand-objective-c-code